# Why do options["foo"] || options.foo?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Reading through the knockout.js source code I come accross [this line](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/subscribables/dependentObservable.js#L173)

```
disposeWhenOption = options["disposeWhen"] || options.disposeWhen
```

I've never seen this before and everything I know about javascript says there is no case when the two sides of the `||` would be different. Why might have the knockout team used this construct?

Comment: Isn't that the same reference just one in dot notation vs. bracket notation?

Comment: I can't seem to make sense of this... It looks redundant.

Comment: @RUJordan exactly, so why use it? This is clearly in a very fine tuned method and the knockout team is a very smart team. I doubt that this is an oversight.

Comment: Dunno, the whole file looks a bit messy, mixing single and double quotes, and not using dot notation sometimes... I imagine JSHint must throw some warnings. Maybe it follows some internal style guide or conventions...

Comment: @elclanrs I imagine, but jshint complains plenty about stuff I do too,  I simply disagree with its reasoning. This file definitely looks a bit messy but the depndentObservable/computed feature this is implementing is probably the most impressive feature in all of knockout and does a fair amount of the library's heavy lifting.

Comment: JSHint is just there in your build step, you configure it and it gets out of the way; I've never found a warning that couldn't be turned off. Knockout is not using a linter, maybe that's why that code got into production or maybe not. I found [this old issue](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/495).

Comment: Interesting, this thread was from long before the big 3.0 rewrite but some of the wording in the comments implies that this might be a result of the closure compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes as a result of symbol mangling performed by the Closure Compiler.  From the [Closure Compiler docs](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#propnames):

> Closure Compiler compilation never changes string literals in your code, no
>   matter what compilation level you use. This means that compilation with
>   ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS treats properties differently depending on whether your
>   code accesses them with a string. If you mix string references to a property
>   with dot-syntax references, Closure Compiler renames some of the references to
>   that property but not others. As a result, your code will probably not run
>   correctly.

Using both the dot syntax and the string literal is the "safe" way to work around this, as it helps ensure a client using an unexported part of the API but not using the closure compiler on their own code will not have any problems.